# Debugging HTTPS .net core application from Android/iOS device

Tags: android, ios, ssl, asp.net-core

I'm using .NET Core 2.1 for a web app.  I'm trying to use SSL with a self-signed certificate (which works a-ok on Windows).  But trying to access these websites on my test device, or the emulator, doesn't work because the .net core certificate isn't working because the certificate isn't on these devices. That makes sense.

I have to use SSL because I am trying to use OpenIddict and Identity Model for app authentication, and (at least) the UWP client won't work on a non-ssl connection (which, for development, I think is silly, but is besides the point)

How can I generate a certificate for use by Kestrel/.NET Core, and then trust that certificate on an Android or iOS device? It's not as easy as just installing the certificate on the intended device, the site is still untrusted.

Comment: for iOS only - when you install the certificate on the device - is it available in `Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings`? And if so, set to `enabled`?

Comment: It's not available there.  I think the reason why is because it doesn't have the right CA setting or something.